# loop through $_POST array using mysql values

Tags: php, mysql, html, smarty

Here is what I have: 
the input type text boxes are dynamically rendered from the database. code as follow:

```
{foreach from = $folderslist item=List}
    <input type="text" name="{$List.widgetid}" id="wcolor" value="{$List.color}" maxlength="6" onChange="display_screenplay_color('fcolor_id',this.value)" style="width:48px;">    
    <span style="color:#{$List.color}">{$List.items} </span>
{/foreach}
```

the column is `widgetid`.
so for each widgetid we want the field name and a textbox next to it with an `id="$idfromdb"`
That way after you hit SUBMIT it posts all the data. I want a loop that will update the db with the values of the textbox. I was wondering if I can Loop through `$_POST` but use regular expressions since all widget ids start with a "w" OR I can get the submitted value `$_POST` of each textbox, their ids start with a "w". or any other ideas/suggestions?

Comment: PLEASE post HTML code you have issues with.

Comment: the code you see generates the boxes for each result. not sure what html you are talking about

Comment: be careful not to set `id="color"` for every input you produce. `id`s must be unique for the whole html-document. just append it with your (hopefully) unique `id="wcolor_{$List.widgetid}"`.

Comment: HTML that forms the form. **Unfortunately I have no Smarty interpreter built-in my head**, so, I cannot say what HTML you get as a result. Your question is about HTML form and POST. So, writing some smarty code makes no sense. Got it?

Comment: @Shrapnel: How do you plan to answer questions related to smarty if you don't know how smarty works? It's just a simple `foreach`-loop and some `echos`s on variables; no need to downvote a reasonable question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `name[]` or `name[id]` as the name of an input and PHP will convert this into an associated array for you.

```
<form action="test.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="widget[5]" id="widget_5" value="5" />
    <input type="text" name="widget[6]" id="widget_6" value="6" />
    <input type="text" name="widget[9]" id="widget_9" value="9" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

$_POST will include this information

```
array
  'widget' => 
    array
      5 => string '5' (length=1)
      6 => string '6' (length=1)
      9 => string '9' (length=1)
```

you can now loop though this with

```
foreach ($_POST["widget"] as $widgetId => $value)
    [...]
```

Comment: everything seems to work thank you,where do I get widgetIDs? is this correct: <input type="hidden" name="widgetid[]" value="{$List.widgetid}" />

Comment: if you just use `name="widgetid[]"` without an id, PHP will index your array manually counting from 0. this is helpful for creating new tuples, but not for editing old ones. try `<input type="text" name="widget[{$List.widgetid}]" id="widget_{$List.widgetid}" value="{$List.color}" />` in your `{foreach}`-loop. you can simply remove the `id` from your input as it is not required for just posting data with a form.

Comment: what I meant was the $_POST["widget"] value needs to be updated under the widgetId: foreach ($_POST["widget"] as $widgetid => $value)
{ $sqlw="UPDATE hpoptions SET color='".$value."' WHERE widgetid ='".$widgetid."' ";
    $db->query($sqlw);}

Comment: if you copied my example, you will have to put an upper case i in `$widgetId`.

Comment: or did you put `name="widgetid[]"`? you will then have to loop over `$_POST["widgetid"]` instead.